# No se guarda imagen al actualizar en laravel 8

Tags: imagen, laravel-8, storage

Estoy utilizando storage para guardar imágenes, en el formulario de crear funciona perfectamente pero cuando voy actualizar un registro que tenga o no imagen no me lo guarda.

También trato de mostrar en un modal la imagen ya cargada y tampoco la muestra solo me muestra en el formulario editar.

Antes de crear codigo ejecute:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Este es el controlador con la funcion de guardar el articulo con la imagen y me funciona perfectamente

```
 public function store(AgregarArticuloFormRequest $request)
    {

        $articulo = new Articulo($request->all());

        $articulo->estado = 'A';
        $articulo->stock = 0;
        $articulo->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;
        //si el input tiene archivo


        if ($request->file('imagen')) {

            $path = $request->file('imagen')->store('public/img/articulos');

            $articulo->imagen = $path;
        }

        //guardamos la validacion
        $articulo->save();

        Alert::success('Registrado', 'Articulo creado correctamente');

        return Redirect::to('articulos');
    }
```

Este es el formulario para crear, reutilizo el formulario form para crear y editar el formulario

```
@extends('layouts.plantilla')

@push('css')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/select2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@section('migas')
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('articulos.index') }}">Articulos</a></li>
@endsection
@section('modulo', 'Crear Articulo')

@section('contenido')
    <section class="content">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">
                    Creación de articulo
                </h3>
            </div>
            <form action="{{ route('articulos.store') }}" method="POST" autocomplete=off enctype="multipart/form-data">

                @include('articulos.form')

                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-4">Guardar</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4">Limpiar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger col-xs-4" href="{{ route('articulos.index') }}">Cancelar</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
@push('js')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/i18n/es.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.categorias').select2();

        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Formulario form.blade

```
{{-- formulario para reutilizar: crear y actualizar --}}
@csrf
<div class="card-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-12">Codigo

                    <input type="text" name="codigo" class="form-control" aria-describedby="codigo"
                        value="{{ $articulo ? $articulo->codigo : old('codigo') }}">
                    @error('codigo')
                        <small class="text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </small>
                    @enderror
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-12">Nombre

                    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" aria-describedby="nombre"
                        value="{{ $articulo ? $articulo->nombre : old('nombre') }}">
                    @error('nombre')
                        <small class="text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </small>
                    @enderror
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-12">Descripcion
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion"
                        value="{{ $articulo ? $articulo->descripcion : old('descripcion') }}">
                    @error('descripcion')
                        <small class="text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </small>
                    @enderror
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Categoria
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control categorias" name="categoria_id">
                        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccione la categoria</option>
                        <!--bucle para recorrer las categorias-->
                        @foreach ($categorias as $cat)
                            <!--si la categoria es la misma id de la categoria articulo mostrar seleccion-->
                            @if ($cat->id == $articulo->categoria_id)
                                <option value="{{ $cat->id }}" selected>
                                    {{ $cat->nombre }}
                                </option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">
                                    {{ $cat->nombre }}
                                </option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        @error('categoria_id')
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </small>
                        @enderror
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="imagen">
                        imagen
                    </label>
                    <!--si el texto esta validado muestra el imagen ingresado-->
                    <input class="form-control" name="imagen" type="file" accept="image/*" />
                    <!--si el campo imagen no esta vacio mostrar la imagen actual-->
                    @if ($articulo->imagen != '')
                        <img src="{{ Storage::url($articulo->imagen) }}" height="200" width="200"
                            alt="" />
                        {{-- <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/' . $articulo->imagen) }}" width="300px" height="300"> --}}
                    @endif
                    @error('imagen')
                        <small class="text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

este es el registro que queda en la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle editar el registro si me carga la imagen y abro consola y me muestra la ruta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion para actualizar el registro

```
public function update(ActualizarArticuloFormRequest $request, Articulo $articulo)
    {
        // dd($request->errors);
        // dd($articulo);
        $articulo->update($request->all());
        $articulo->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;

        //si el input tiene archivo
        if ($request->hasFile('imagen')) {
            $request->validate([
                'imagen' => 'nullable|file|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
              ]);
            $path = $request->file('imagen')->store('public/img/articulos');
            $articulo->imagen = $path;
        }
        // dd($articulo->imagen);

        $articulo->save();

        Alert::success('Articulo actualizado correctamente');

        return Redirect::to('articulos');
    }
```

Este es el registro que queda en la BD despues de actualizar(queda solo el nombre de la imagen y no la ruta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy al formulario editar y abro consola me sale esta ruta de la imagen y no carga. ademas tampoco queda en la carpeta articulos la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo `web.php` para las rutas

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PermisoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController;

Route::get('/panel', function () {
    return view('panel');
})->name('panel');

Route::resource('articulos', ArticuloController::class)->names('articulos');
Route::patch('articulos/{articulo}/update', [ArticuloController::class,'update'])->name('articulos.update');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un colega de FB logro ver lo que faltaba para que funcionara y fue lo sgt:

En el formulario de actualizar faltaba la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
y lo otro es que no había pasado en el controlador index el campo imagen.